# Using username and password stored through sharedpreferences in Android app in Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

How does one use a Android app username and password stored through sharedpreferences in google app engine? And I want to be able to use the username as an entity key in my datastore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what you are trying to do here.

Here are some points:

- The communication between an Android application and a Google App Engine application will primarily be over HTTP. The ideal way will be to develop a HTTP-based Web Service on App Engine that is able to take HTTP requests from your Android Application.
- One the Web Service interface is defined, you should be able to invoke the Web Service, its methods and the request parameters that it expects. I assume you would want to pass the username in one of your request parameters and the Web Service method implementation could then check it against the App Engine Datastore entity.
- Having said that, I would caution that it is generally not good practice to be sending across the plain text password from your Android application over the network to any Server side service.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This HTTP-based web service could be a java Servlet right?